# snmpwalk: SysUpTime incorrect

Tags: snmp, cisco, net-snmp

I keep track of a cisco's UpTime.
*sh ver* shows me 1year 221 days
But when I want to get a sysuptime via snmpwalk I'm getting a response like:

> snmpwalk -v1 -c public xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3
>
> > DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (776591904) 89 days, 21:11:59.04

OID=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3 means sysUpTime in MIB.

Any ideas why it's different?

Comment: As I can see this link https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10349561/snmp-uptime explains that sysUpTime is a 32-bit counter and will roll over after 496 days.
Anyone knows that is correct for CISCO ASA5200 with 9.1(1) Firmware? 
And also how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

SNMP has its design limitation, as you discovered,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#page-24

The biggest value is about 1 year and 132 days. So in your case, 132 + 89 is roughly 221.

There is no way to fix such by design things, and you simply accept the fact.

Comment: Thanx for reply!  
Is there an example how to configure a NMS for UpTime monitoring aсcording to snmp has 32 bit limitation for UpTimeSys?